# Letter not in "a"-"z" dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I want to know if a letter is in range "a"-"z", so if the character isn't a letter (for example "!") then must return false, otherwise (if is a litter lowercase) return true.

EDIT : To be more clear I'll write an example.

```
bool validate( String x ) {
    if ( "a" <= x[0] && x[0] <= "z" ) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: How is the input given? Just a `String` containing a single letter?

Comment: Yes, something like "String x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution coded as an extension, taking into account case-sensitivity.

```
void main() {
  print('h'.isAz());                        // true
  print('E'.isAz());                        // false
  print('Y'.isAz(caseSensitive: false));    // true
  print('!'.isAz());                        // false
  print('!'.isAz(caseSensitive: false));    // false
}

extension StringX on String {
  isAz({caseSensitive = true}) {
    final target = caseSensitive ? this : this.toLowerCase();
    return target.codeUnitAt(0) > 96 && target.codeUnitAt(0) < 123;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance use [String::codeUnitAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/codeUnitAt.html)

```
var a = 'a'.codeUnitAt(0);
var z = 'z'.codeUnitAt(0);
  
var x = 'x'.codeUnitAt(0);
var qm = '?'.codeUnitAt(0);

print(a <= x && x <= z);
print(a <= qm && qm <= z);
```

Comment: So something like : if ( 'a'.codeUnitAt(0) <= x[0] && x[0] <= 'z'.codeUnitAt(0) ) return true else false

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for checking a single letter you can do something like this with a regular expression:

```
void main() {
  print(isLetter('a')); // true
  print(isLetter('!')); // false
}

RegExp _isLetterRegExp = RegExp(r'[a-z]', caseSensitive: false);
bool isLetter(String letter) => _isLetterRegExp.hasMatch(letter);
```